# Name conflict between Swift class function and bridged C function

Tags: swift

I have a Swift 4 project that imports a library written in plain C. A bridging header is set up and working. I only have one problem: the C library contains a function `computeFoo` that I want to wrap as a static class function with the same name in Swift:

```
class Foo {
    static func computeFoo(a: Double, b: Double) -> Double {
        return computeFoo(a, b)
    }
}
```

When compiling this, Xcode complains correctly:

> Use of 'computeFoo' refers to static method 'computeFoo(a: Double, b: Double)' rather than global function 'computeFoo' in module '__ObjC'
>
> Use '__ObjC.' to reference the global function in module '__ObjC'

However, the proposed fix also won't compile:

```
static func computeFoo(a: Double, b: Double) -> Double {
    return __ObjC.computeFoo(a, b)
}
```

results in:

> Use of unresolved identifier '__ObjC'

Is it possible to have those function names equal or do I have to rename one of the functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you first should try is adding your ProductModuleName to global functions:

```
class Foo {
    static func computeFoo(a: Double, b: Double) -> Double {
        return ProductModuleName.computeFoo(a, b)
    }
}
```

(Assuming you know your `ProductModuleName`.)

If this does not solve your issue, you may need to clarify more info about it.